# Java Array Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

The purpose of this assignment is to learn recursive methods. For this particular problem, I need to print the values of `list`, one per line. The skeleton of the method I need to complete cannot be changed and is as follows:

```
public void list (String[] list) {

}
```

The instructions say that helper methods may make this easier to write. Here is what I have for my helper method:

```
public void print(String[] list, int index) {    
      if (index < list.length) {
          System.out.println(list[index]);
          print(list, index+1);
      }
}
```

I would just like to call the print method through the list method for testing. I know the grading is done through a script, so again I cannot change the return type or parameters of the list method. Please excuse my formatting errors, and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @Jeremiah - Usually when you see nonsensical stuff like that it's just a beginner making a code formatting error. Click edit yourself and you can see where they went wrong and fix it. I've already done so. It's usually pretty obvious where the mistake is and it helps everyone if you fix it.

Comment: Go to class, pay attention, read the book, ask questions, try the assignment, then come here with what you've got.

Comment: @Shakedown the problem is that people has already gave the code to the guy :D and now he will not go to the next class, will not read the book, neither ask question, nor try the assignment :D

Comment: @Serhiy: You're right, and that's the problem with people eager to give an answer just to get reputation on the site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this I would use a helper method with the name of `print()` or something similar.

In terms of thinking about the logic of the program, think about what you would need to do:

Have a helper method `print()` that:

- Prints the current item in the list, on a new line
- It then calls a function to print the next and subsequent items in the list, each on new lines

What do you think that second function could be? *Hint: It's recursive...*

Comment: One other note for Dan: Feel free to comment on our responses, so that we can engage in a dialog here to try to help you. We don't want to give you the answers to your homework, but are willing to help you along as long as you make an effort to increase your understanding and have a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

There are [lots of good examples](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=java+recursion) of [recursion in Java](http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch18-recurex/index.html). You would benefit greatly from reading these. First read your textbook, then continue with these examples

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you direct answer, since you won't learn anything from it. You can create the variable to store current depth. Create getter and setter helper methods to increase the depth of recursion. Your method list, will call itself, with the same array, but only after you check that the depth is not bigger then the size of array. Don't forget to increase the depth of the recursion on every call.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a recursive solution like this: given a bunch of things (like a list) do something with one of those things (like the first element of the list), then pass the rest of the things *to the same solution that processed one of the things*

Hint: you need to think about what your solution does in the case when it's given nothing.

Hint 2: Instead of "chopping up" the array each time you recurse, just note your place in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning:

You probably already know that a recursive function is one that calls itself.  If every time a function runs it calls itself, you are going to end up in an infinite loop.  Therefore, it is important to always make sure your function knows when to stop calling itself as well.

How can we do this?  The body of the function is not going to change between calls, since it is set at compile time.  What will change, however, is the input to the function.  Whenever you write a recursive function, you need to include logic that will avoid the recursive call when a certain condition is met.

In your example, the input to your function is an array of Strings.  One way to know when to stop making the recursive call could be to pass a smaller array to the function each time, and stop when you have an empty array.  This would work better in a language like C where arrays are exposed as pointers, but in Java it would be inefficient as you would have to create a new array each time.

A nicer solution would be to maintain an index pointing to your current position in the list (this is why you need a helper function - to add the extra parameter).  At each call, you can simply print the String at the current index and increment the index.  When the index is no longer inside the array, you're done!

If you really want to get a good understanding of recursion, I recommend learning a functional language such as Lisp, Haskell, or ML.  Functional languages avoid mutable state (changing the values of variables), and as such they don't use things like for loops (because of the need to update a loop counter at every iteration).  So they implement loops using recursion instead!  For example, in Java we might have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println("Loop index: " + i);
}
```

whereas in OCaml we would write the following:

```
let times = 10 in
let rec loop count =
  if count = times then
    printf "Loop index: %d" count ;
    loop (count + 1)
;;
```

The important difference here is that, rather than changing the value of count (actually not possible given the above OCaml code), we pass a new value into the `loop` function each time.

Answer (score 0):

When your doing recursion, it can sometimes be helpful to write out how you would perform the same task using a loop:

```
public void list(String[] list) {
    for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(list[index]);
    }
}
```

Now, say we wanted to get closer to a recursive solution. The first step might be to get rid of the interior part of the `for` loop:

```
public void list(String[] list) {
    for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        list(list, index);
    }
}

public void list(String[] list, int index) {
    System.out.println(list[index]);
}
```

Okay, now we are really close to the recursive solution. We just need to take the last two tasks that the loop is handling, incrementing `index` and checking if `index < list.length`. These look like they might be great candidates for a reduction step and a base case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the much good way even though it will be helpful.

```
static void traverse(int []x)
{
    if(x.length == 0)
        return;

    traverse( Arrays.copyOf(x,x.length- 1));

    System.out.println(x[x.length-1]);

}
```